# In a django data model, is there any way to create a data field for each json attribute stored in a postgres table?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

Suppose I have the following Postgres Table containing a column that holds json values:

```
    +----+-------------------------------------------------+
    | id |                     record                      |
    +----+-------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | {"0":"1st value","1":"a value","2":"I value"}   |
    |  2 | {"0":"2nd value","1":"b value","2":"II value"}  |
    |  3 | {"0":"3rd value","1":"c value","2":"III value"} |
    |  4 | {"0":"4th value","1":"d value","2":"IV value"}  |
    +----+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to create a django data model for this table in which there is a field for each of the json attributes.  Something like this:

```
    class RecordTable(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        zero = models.TextField(db_column='record->\'0\'')
        one = models.TextField(db_column='record->\'1\'')
        two = models.TextField(db_column='record->\'2\'')

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'record_table'
```

This is close but does not generate the kind of queries I would like.  Django will ultimately generate select statements like the one below due to how it handles the column names:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT "record_table"."record->'0'" FROM "record_table" ...
```

When I really want the generated queries to look like this (notice the lack of quotes around record->'0'):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT "record_table".record->'0' FROM "record_table" ...
```

I have looked at the documentation on custom fields and custom managers but I haven't found any functionality that allows me to split up json values into multiple data fields like this.  Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.8 has an [`HStoreField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) that you might find useful, and Django 1.9 will have a [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).

However, I don't think that having multiple Django fields referring to the same column in the table is feasible.